# For loop for files in a directory

Tags: shell, for-loop

I am trying to loop through all of the files in a directory and

1. move them to a workspace (I need to do this to do this because the workspace doesn't have much storage).
2. Run a program which produces an output directory that contains all the files I will want to work with in the future
3. Delete the original file from the workspace (to save space in the workspace)and
4. Move the output directory out of the workspace and back to the storage space

I am able to do this for each file singly (i.e. each line works if I actually use the name of the files), but I can't get the for loop to work. I am quite new to this, so I probably did something simple wrong.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
for i in path_to_files; do

    #copy to home directory (from scratch)
    cp $i .



    #Run IDBA
    idba_ud -l $i -o '$i'_out

    #remove file from work directory (limited space)

    rm $i

    #copy out directory back to scratch 
    cp -r '$i'_out path_to_files

done
```

I keep getting an error that says

> syntax error near unexpected token `cp'.

I have also tried replacing cp with copy and i/$i with file/$file with no luck.

Comment: what language is this? Looks like bash/shell...

Comment: It is hopefully going to be a shell script.

Comment: what's `cp -r '$i'_out` supposed to to? recursively copy the file with the `_out` suffix to the original directory? this is not what you asked for...

Comment: The idba command produces an output directory. That is indicated by -o directoryname My goal was to produce this directory and have it be named  $i_out (so whatever the name of the original file was, and then the added _out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is indeed *POSIX compatible shell* (your code looks suspiciously like that, but you haven't specified the actually used shell), then:

- You should *always* quote filenames, in case it contains spaces or other *weird* characters:
- But you should *not* use single-quotes, as this will prevent shell from expanding your variables.
- when appending text to substituted variables, use `${}` notation (e.g. if `$i` expands to "murgel", then `${i}foo` will expand to "murgelfoo", whereas `$ifoo` will expand to "" (an empty string) if there is no variable `ifoo`)

Thus try:

```
filepath=/path/to/files

for i in "${filepath}"/*; do
    #copy to home directory (from scratch)
    cp "${i}" .
    #Run IDBA
    idba_ud -l "${i}" -o "${i}_out"
    #remove file from work directory (limited space)
    rm $i
    #copy out directory back to scratch 
    cp "${i}_out"/* "${filepath}"/
done
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much for the help! You explanation was very useful. I do, however, have one more problem. Now I can get the commands to work (i.e. this problem was solved) but I am getting the error "cp: cannot stat `{/path/to/files/*}': No such file or directory" However, I know both from copying the files by hand and by checking it out with pwd that the path is correct. Any ideas?